# Split string in classic asp

Tags: string, asp-classic

I am working in classic ASP and have a string as below :

A
B
C

Now I want to split the string, I have tried vbCrLf, vbNewline , vblf and 
 but none of them work.

Please suggest me an alternative to split the string. I am in a bad fix.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure, you have newlines in the string?

First you can output all character codes to find out, by which character to split:

```
dim i, c

for i = 1 to len(my_string)
    c = mid(my_string, i, 1)
    Response.Write "CHAR: " & ASC(c) & " = " & c
next
```

Then you have 2 options:

1. If you can split by one character (e.g. char num 10), you can use:

   ```
   a_result = split(my_string, CHR(10))
   ```
2. You can grab values out of your string by using regular expression matching. This is much overhead, but if all else fails, here is how you could do that:

   ```vbs
   function findStrings(s_text, s_pattern)
           dim a_out, obj_regex, obj_matches
           dim obj_match, n_index
           set obj_regex = New RegExp

           obj_regex.IgnoreCase = true
           obj_regex.Global = true
           obj_regex.MultiLine = true
           obj_regex.Pattern = s_pattern
           set obj_matches = obj_regex.execute(s_text)
           if obj_matches.Count>0 then
                   redim a_out(obj_matches.Count-1)
                   n_index = 0
                   for each obj_match in obj_matches
                           a_out(n_index) = cvStr(obj_match.Value)
                           n_index = n_index + 1
                   next
           end if
           findStrings = a_out
           set obj_regex = Nothing
   end function

   a_result = findStrings(my_string, "\w+")
   ```

This assumes, that there is no whitespace in the strings you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This happens more often than you think, you need to remove the vbcr first then replace only vblf and forget about spliting on vbcrlf because it wont work for 100% of the user envrioments out there.

```
A
B
C

' assuming about is in the variable str

split(replace(str,vbcr,""),vblf)
```

Comment: This won't work if the newline is only a vbcr. What I usually do is convert any vblf to vbcr, then convert any vbcr-vbcr to a single vbcr. This will guarantee that all newlines are just vbcr.