# How to split a string in classic asp

Tags: arrays, string, vbscript, split, asp-classic

I am trying to split a string in a classic asp application, have below code in the page and it does not seem to work. There is another question which looks similar but deals with different type of problem, I have already been to the answers there and they don't help. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<% 
Dim SelectedCountries,CitizenshipCountry, Count 
SelectedCountries = "IN, CH, US"    
CitizenshipCountry = Split(SelectedCountries,", ")
Count = UBound(CitizenshipCountry) + 1 
Response.Write(CitizenshipCountry[0])
Response.End
%>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string in classic asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058903/split-string-in-classic-asp)

Comment: @Lankymart Sorry but that does not seem to help hence had to post a new question.

Comment: Your `Split()` is working and creating an array called `CitizenshipCountry`. The issue is you then try to work out the number of elements of a string variable `SelectedCountries` instead of checking the array `UBound(CitizenshipCountry)`. Also, VBScript arrays use curly brackets like this not square ones like other languages `CitizenshipCountry(0)`.

Comment: @Lankymart Sorry that was a typo, have edited the code in question now. Ok will try the curly brackets.

Comment: This is a curly bracket: `{`. This is a parenthesis: `(`. VBScript does not use brackets of any sort, neither square, curly, nor fluorescent magenta. It *does* use parentheses.

Comment: @Martha Ok, point taken, you're arguing semantics though...let me ask you this, does my code in the comment or answer use *braces* *(`{ }`)* anywhere?....I didn't think so, thanks for [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42093089/3) anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've made a couple of mistakes which is why you are not getting the expected result.

1. When checking the bounds of an Array you need to specify the Array variable, in this case, the variable generated by `Split()` which is `CitizenshipCountry`.
2. Array elements are accessed by specifying the element ordinal position in parentheses *(`(...)`)* not square brackets *(`[...]`)*.

Try this:

```
<% 
Dim SelectedCountries, CitizenshipCountry, Count 
SelectedCountries = "IN, CH, US"    
CitizenshipCountry = Split(SelectedCountries,", ")
'Get the count of the array not the string.
Count = UBound(CitizenshipCountry)
'Use (..) when referencing array elements.
Call Response.Write(CitizenshipCountry(0))
Call Response.End()
%>
```

What I like to do is use `IsArray` to check the variable contains a valid array before calling `UBound()` to avoid these types of errors.

```
<% 
Dim SelectedCountries, CitizenshipCountry, Count 
SelectedCountries = "IN, CH, US"    
CitizenshipCountry = Split(SelectedCountries,", ")
'Get the count of the array not the string.
If IsArray(CitizenshipCountry) Then
  Count = UBound(CitizenshipCountry)
  'Use (..) when referencing array elements.
  Call Response.Write(CitizenshipCountry(0))
Else
  Call Response.Write("Not an Array")
End If
Call Response.End()
%>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm, I am new to classis asp, never used before just need to do some fix on an old app, thanks for the help :) (Y).

Comment: Thanks for [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42093089/3) @Martha that reads better.

Comment: @Lankymart, idle question: any particular reason you're using `Call Response.Write("my string")` instead of `Response.Write "my string"`?

Comment: @martha because that is my coding style. I find it beneficial for determining at a glance the difference between variables and a Sub Procedure calls. It is purely personal preference.